# How to edit Dropbox files in Office Online using Dropbox API

Tags: dropbox-api

I integrated Dropbox into my application. So I want to open and edit MS Office

files. In Dropbox app that is collaborate with Office Online to edit. Is there any

way to implement from the Dropbox API. Please give me a idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Dropbox doesn't offer a way to use the Dropbox/Office Online integration via the Dropbox API. We'll consider this a feature request.